# Missing photograph

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**Which person's photograph should be pasted upright (NOT UPSIDE DOWN) in the blank space?**
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The missing photograph is one of:

> [**Werner von Siemens**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_von_Siemens), the scientist after whom the SI unit *siemens* is named.
>
>  [image: Werner von Siemens]

To work this out, first identify the pictured people. These are all:

> Scientists who have units named after them:
>
>  Charles-Augustin de Coulomb
>  Joseph Henry
>  Georg Ohm
>  Nikola Tesla
>  Alessandro Volta
>
>  Each of these units has a single-character symbol: Coulomb (C), Henry (H), Ohm (Ω), Tesla (T), Volt (V). Now to generate the second row of images,  imagine we replace the images with the corresponding unit symbols, and reflect these characters in a horizontal line beneath them...
>
>  Whilst reflecting the 'T' and 'V' gives 'an upside-down T' and 'an upside-down V' (explaining why the corresponding photographs of scientists are shown reflected), the 'C' and 'H' (being horizontally symmetrical) are unchanged, thus Coulomb's and Henry's pictures are shown the same way up as before in the second row.

This means we need to identify...

> ...a scientist after whom a unit was named, whose symbol is **an upside-down omega** (i.e. the symbol for Ohm, reflected horizontally): ℧.

This would be:

> Werner von Siemens, as the [siemens unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens_(unit)#Mho) (whose symbol is traditionally a capital 'S') has also historically been named the **mho** - 'ohm' backwards, since the ohm and the siemens represent properties that are the *reciprocal* of one another: electrical resistance and electrical conductance - and the symbol of the mho is the upside-down capital omega we require.